# Find all the elements of a list whose field match with a value

Tags: python, list, generator

If I have a list like this:

```
[element(name='A', value=0), element(name='B', value=1)]
```

I would like to find all the element of the list whose value field is equal to 0:

```
element[:].value == 0
```

Which would the shortest way?

Comment: What are those...? Named tuples? Can you give more details?

Comment: Im guessing this is what you meant list1 = [{'name':1, "value":2}, {'name':1, "value":2}]. List of dictionary elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elements = [element(name='A', value=0), element(name='B', value=1)]
matches = [element for element in elements if element.value == 0]
```

---

To get the names from all the matches:

```
names = [element.name for element in matches]
print(names)
```

Comment: And if I do matches = [element for element in elements if element.value == 0], how could I print(matches[:].name)?

Comment: @Rafa Updated my answer to answer your question.

Comment: Could I do directly?

matches = [element.name for element in elements if element.value == 0]

Comment: @Rafa Yes you can!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension should do the trick

```
not_values = [e for e in elements if not e.value]
```

Please note I'm using `not e.value` because I think it reads better and it's more coherent with the variable name `not_values` but you could also use `e.value == 0`.

Comment: What if `e.value` is `[]` or `False`?

Comment: God point. It all depends on the preconditions of your contract. Whether you expect elements to contain any Falsey value and how you should handle those cases. i.e. would you filter them out or not?